# Strange AngularJS beginner behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am starting learning AngularJS but I've stumbled across a strange behavior I can't quite understand where the (() => {}) notation is not equivalent to (function(){}).

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Store</title>
    <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
      <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
      <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
      <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js (closure stripped for debugging).

```
var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

app.controller("StoreController", function() {
    this.product = gem;
});

var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .'
};
```

In app.js, if I change

```
app.controller("StoreController", function() {
    this.product = gem;
});
```

to

```
app.controller("StoreController", () => {
    this.product = gem;
});
```

My page no longer displays the gem information(just blanks and the dollar sign remain).

Can somebody explain why this happens?

AngularJS version: v1.5.6
Opera version: 37.0.2178.54

Comment: I am not sure if Angular allows `() =>` notation. Is there any code where you've used `() =>` and it works properly ?

Comment: did you try to compile your code with babel or webpack? not all browsers support ES6

Comment: Arrow functions have implicit `this` binding, which means that the value of the `this` value inside of an arrow function is aways the same as the value of `this` in the scope in which the arrow function is defined! - [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: PirateX, this is the first situation where arrow didn't work for me O.o.
MaximShoustin, not sure what you mean.
CosminAbabei, you seem to be right; I think the "this.product" does not mutate the outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use arrow functions if you need `this` context.

Read more here(13.2): http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: I think this is the case. It seems to me that arrow functions can't mutate the closure they are contained in.